# Reading frames from CIF video in OpenCV 2.4.2

Tags: c++, c, opencv

The problem is the following:

There is a CIF video file that is supposed to be processed by the OpenCV.
Unfortunately, I am not able to read frames from this video. The following code

```
cv::VideoCapture cap = cv::VideoCapture("foreman.cif");
if(!cap.isOpened()) {
    std::cout << "Open file error" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

gives `Open file error` in console.

Is there any way to grab frames from CIF video using OpenCV?

Comment: Is it an AVI in CIF format or a raw cif image sequence? What codec is it using (raw YUV or h264)? Can you open it in anything else (ffmpeg, VLC etc)

Comment: There is a way to install OpenCV with FFmpeg, in which case I think it might be possible, it's been a little while since I have done anything in openCV.  What type of installation are you dealing with?

Comment: @MartinBeckett It's a raw YUV sequence.

Comment: @RustyWeber I compiled OpenCV by myself with Ubuntu

Comment: @Alex Have you followed the directions on the following web page to enable ffmepg inside of your openCV compile http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FFMPEG ?  P.S.  After you install the packages you may need a recompile.. SRY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think openCV can read raw YUV streams directly.
You can use memcoder to convert it to an avi, compressed or not.
Or you can use regular c/c++ to read the data blocks, copy them into an image and use cvCvtColor() to convert YUV->BGR